# FCKeditor Toolbar in asp

Tags: asp-classic, fckeditor

I have a custom toolbar defined in a config.js file for an FCKeditor.  I am not sure how to go about implementing this toolbar in asp.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't view the site (my job considers it freeware and a danger to the network) but you can specify which toolbar you use when  you create the COM instance.

http://docs.fckeditor.net/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Integration/ASP

**EDIT:  THERE IT IS!**
http://docs.fckeditor.net/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Toolbar

```
<%
Dim oFCKeditor
Set oFCKeditor = New FCKeditor
oFCKeditor.BasePath = "/fckeditor/"
oFCKeditor.ToolbarSet = "MyToolbar"
oFCKeditor.Value = "<p>This is some <strong>sample text</strong>. You are using <a href=""http://www.fckeditor.net/"">FCKeditor</a>."
oFCKeditor.Create "FCKeditor1"
%>
```